# Django Admin: How to access the request object in admin.py, for list_display methods?

Tags: django, django-admin, request

I've added a method `highlight_link` to my model's admin.py class:

```
class RadioGridAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    list_display = ('start_time', highlight_link)
    
    def highlight_link(self):
        return ('some custom link')
    
    
admin.site.register(RadioGrid, RadioGridAdmin)
```

It returns a custom link for (I've left out `highlight_link.short_description` for brevity) each record returned in the change list.  Which is great.  But I'd like to inspect the current query string and change the custom link based on that.  Is there a way to access the request object within `highlight_link`?

Comment: I'd like to point out this related ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the other answers left here and ran into issues that for me, were getting complex.  I played around with `def __call__()` and came up with the following.  This probably isn't the correct way to do this, but it works...

grab the GET variable here (all within class RadioGridAdmin as described above in my initial post):

```
def __call__(self, request, url):
     global start_date
     start_date = request.GET['param']

     return super(RadioGridAdmin, self).__call__(request, url)
```

and since it's global, you can now access it here:

```
def highlight_link(self):
    # access start_date here
```

Comment: globals are dangerous in the context of multi-threaded environments, such as running in mod_phyton on apache server.

Answer (score 34):

I solve my issue this way (for django under 1.7):

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyClassAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        self.request = request
        return qs
```

Now i can use `self.request` in any place

**UPDATE**

> [Changed in Django 1.6:
> The get_queryset method was previously named queryset.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyClassAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        self.request = request
        return qs
```

Comment: Still seems to work, but `queryset` must now be replaced with `get_queryset`.

Comment: Still  works in 1.9 but `queryset` must now be replaced with `get_queryset`.

Comment: I seems nobody really tried this solution, It appears "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

Comment: @fsalazar_sch the name error smells like you forgot the "self" first parameter of the method.

Comment: could anybody with the knowledget elaborate why this solution is not thread safe?

Answer (score 20):

```
class RadioGridAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def highlight_link(self, obj):
        return (self.param)

   def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        self.param = request.GET['param']
        return super(RadioGridAdmin,self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: Overriding the ModelAdmin's methods is a pretty neat way but the code has some errors:

    "def highlight_link(self):"

should be 

    "def highlight_link(self, obj):"

and 

    "super(RadioGridAdmin, self).changelist_view(...)"

should have a "return" in front.

Comment: @CollinAnderson Why it's not threadsafe? Could you explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: Because the RadioGridAdmin instance (self) is shared between requests.

Comment: @CollinAnderson Thanks! I also found this from the source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/927b30a6ab33ea33e5e3b1e7408ac1d5d267ff6a/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L110

Answer (score 7):

Described how to [refactor this into a mixin](http://marcelchastain.com/2018/05/getting-access-to-request-in-django-modeladmin/), with addition of the thread-safety bit based on @taha-jahangir's answer. Here's the mixin:

```
import threading

class ModelAdminRequestMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # let's define this so there's no chance of AttributeErrors
        self._request_local = threading.local()
        self._request_local.request = None
        super(ModelAdminRequestMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_request(self):
        return self._request_local.request

    def set_request(self, request):
        self._request_local.request = request

    def changeform_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # stash the request
        self.set_request(request)

        # call the parent view method with all the original args
        return super(ModelAdminRequestMixin, self).changeform_view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def add_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_request(request)
        return super(ModelAdminRequestMixin, self).add_view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def change_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_request(request)
        return super(ModelAdminRequestMixin, self).change_view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def changelist_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_request(request)
        return super(ModelAdminRequestMixin, self).changelist_view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_request(request)
        return super(ModelAdminRequestMixin, self).delete_view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def history_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_request(request)
        return super(ModelAdminRequestMixin, self).history_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Subclass ModelAdmin with the mixin:

```
class PollAdmin(ModelAdminRequestMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

... and you can just call `self.get_request()` from any method.

Answer (score 5):

Small code clarify for **Diego Puente** answer (python 3.6):

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, model, admin_site): 
        self.request = None
        super().__init__(model, admin_site)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        self.request = request      
        return super().get_queryset(request)
```

So you can get `self.request` from any other method of `MyClassAdmin`.

If define `self.request` in `get_queryset` method (without declaring it in `__init__`) PyCharm will generate warning `Instance attribute attribute_name defined outside __init__`.

Answer (score 3):

The is no direct way to accomplish this. I see 2 possible solutions.

- Use a thread locals store to same request object

  ```
  from django.utils._threading_local import locals

  globals = locals()

  class RadioGridAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        globals['radio_grid_admin_request'] = request
        return super(RadioGridAdmin, self).__call__(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def highlight_link(self):
        request = globals['radio_grid_admin_request']
        # request.GET processing
        return ('some custom link')
  ```
- If you are using simple non-threaded Django installation it is possible to save request object just as attribute:

  ```
  class RadioGridAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        return super(RadioGridAdmin, self).__call__(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def highlight_link(self):
        # self.request.GET processing
        return ('some custom link')
  ```

Comment: What is the impact using one or the other of these two scenarios?

Comment: @Gelbander Only the first one is safe to use if there is concurrency. Second one is easier but you could get the wrong request object.

Comment: When is the `__call__` method invoked with a `request` argument on a `ModelAdmin` instance? I don't see it anywhere in Django's code.

Comment: As of Django 1.11, there's no `django.utils._threading_local`

Answer (score 3):

This is edited version of @user27478 answer, which uses thread-local vars:

```
class RadioGridAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        super().__init__(model, admin_site)
        self._request_local = threading.local()

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        self._request_local.request = request
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)

    @property
    def _request(self):
        return self._request_local.request

    def example_highlight_link(self, obj):
        changelist = self.get_changelist_instance(self._request)
        url = changelist.get_query_string(new_params={'key1': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading

_thread_local = threading.local()

def get_thread_local_request():
    return getattr(_thread_local, "request", None)

class RadioGridAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('display_field', ...)

    def display_field(self, obj):
        # ...
        request = get_thread_local_request()
        # ...
```

Comment: hello, with django 1.9.6 `from django.core import get_thread_local_request` gives `ImportError: cannot import name 'get_thread_local_request'`. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

### admin_mixins.py

```
from functools import partial, update_wrapper, lru_cache

# Django admin call 2 times get_list_display.
# We need to return the same function to make the method sortable using 'admin_order_field'
# https://github.com/django/django/blob/2161db0792f2e4d3deef3e09cd72f7a08340cafe/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L84
@lru_cache(maxsize=100)
def cache_display_wrap(f, request):
    wf = partial(f, request)
    nf = update_wrapper(wf, f)
    return nf

  
class ModelAdminMixin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        def check_needs_request(display):
            f = getattr(self, display, None) if not callable(display) else display 
            if f and getattr(f, 'needs_request', False):
              return cache_display_wrap(f, request)
            return display
        return [check_needs_request(display) for display in super().get_list_display(request)]
```

### any_app/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from core.admin_mixins import ModelAdminMixin


@admin.register(AnyModel)
class AnyModelAdmin(ModelAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdminMixin):

    list_display = ['id', 'especial_display_with_request']

    def especial_display_with_request(self, request, obj):
        # Make something special with the request
        return obj.any_field
    especial_display_with_request.needs_request = True  # Similar to short_description or any other django admin attr.
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/pricco/24826bae3d5102d963eb13ecc0493f33

Answer (score -2):

What's wrong with this:

```
def highlight_link(self, request):
    # access start_date here
```

Comment: I don't believe that highlight_link would get the request object passed to it.

Comment: When a method is listed as a field, it will be called automatically to generate the HTML for the field, and it is called with a certain set of arguments, `request` is not one of them. Just adding it to the method signature doesn't change how it is called.