# django: how to access current request user in ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-admin

In my implementation of ModelForm, I would like to perform different types of validation checks based on whether current user is superuser. How can I access the current request user?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you can pass the user object as an extra argument in the form constructor.

e.g.

```
f = MyForm(user=request.user)
```

and the constructor will  look like:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
         super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then use user in the clean_XX forms as you wish

Comment: Sorry about not clarifying this in the original question, but my ModelForm was hooked up to a ModelAdmin subclass. How can I invoke the ModelForm's custom constructor from the ModelAdmin?

Comment: so you want to do this within the django admin interface? Have not tried that, but I guess you could try overwriting the __call__ method of the form. e.g something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727928/django-admin-how-to-access-the-request-object-in-admin-py-for-list-display-meth

Answer (score 53):

If you're using Class Based Views (CBVs) then passing an extra argument in the form constructor (e.g. in `get_forms_class`) or in `form_class` will not work, as `<form> object is not callable` will be shown.

The solution for CBVs is to use [`get_form_kwargs()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs), e.g.:

views.py:

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyForm

    # Sending user object to the form, to verify which fields to display/remove (depending on group)
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(MyUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')  # To get request.user. Do not use kwargs.pop('user', None) due to potential security hole

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # If the user does not belong to a certain group, remove the field
        if not self.user.groups.filter(name__iexact='mygroup').exists():
            del self.fields['confidential']
```

Answer (score 16):

My small addition,

I had a requirement where one of the model choice fields of the form is dependent on the `request.user`, and it took a while to take my head around.

The idea is that

1. you need to have a `__init__` method in the model form class,
2. and you access the `request` or other parameters from the arguments of the `__init__` method,
3. then you need to call the super constructor to new up the form class
4. and then you set the `queryset` of the required field

**code sample**

```
class CsvUploadForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(CsvUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['lists'].queryset = List.objects.filter(user=user)

    lists = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, widget=forms.Select, required=True)
```

as you can see, the `lists` variable is dependent on the current user, which is available via `request` object, so we set the `queryset` of the field as null, and its assigned dynamically from the constructor later.

**Take a look into the order of the statements in the above code**

you can pass the user variable like this from the view file

```
form = CsvUploadForm(user=request.user)
```

or with other POST, FILE data like below

```
form = CsvUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
```

Comment: in the __init__ function don't forget to add (user=self.user) just to save some time.

Answer (score 3):

You may reference the user object using the instance attribute within the instance it self.

Ex; `self.instance.user`

```
class StatusForm(ModelForm):

    # def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    #     super(StatusForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Status
        fields = [
            'user',
            'content',
            'image'
        ]

    def clean_content(self):
        content = self.cleaned_data.get("content", None)
        if len(content) > 240:
            raise ValidationError(f"Hey {self.instance.user.username}, the content is too long")
        return content
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, when I am not sending form in context explicitly in get_context_data:

views.py

```
class MyView(FormView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
       kwargs = super(MyView, self).get_form_kwargs()
       kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
       return kwargs
```

form.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
       super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       if not self.user.groups.filter(name__iexact='t1_group').exists():
          del self.fields['test_obj']
```

When sending form explicitly in get_context_data we can use and this is forms.Form :

views.py
class MyView(FormView):
model = MyModel
form_class = MyForm

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.user)
       return context
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, user,*args, **kwargs):
       super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       if not user.groups.filter(name__iexact='t1_group').exists():
          del self.fields['test_obj']
```