# How to get current signed user in forms.py?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I'm using ModelChoiceField to select Invoice provider in my forms. In the current case, I'm returning all the Providers to the queryset.

But I should return only Providers that created by the signed user. Provider has a ForeignKey field named `user`.

Here is my Form:

```
class InvoiceCreationForm(forms.Form):
    # ...
    provider = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Provider',
        required=False,
        queryset=Provider.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={
            'name': 'provider',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'id': 'input-invoice-provider',
        })
    )
```

I need to filter objects like this:

```
Provider.objects.filter(user=current_user)
```

How can I get the signed user? Or how can I get the `request` object outside of a view? I tried get the current user from `__init__` method of the form then set it to `self.user`. But I can't use it in the query like `self.user`.

Comment: Please show the code that you tried.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7300076/4471283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the user in `__init__()` is only the first part of the solution. You also need to use that user to filter the queryset:

```
class InvoiceCreationForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
         super(InvoiceCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         if self.user:
             self.fields['provider'].queryset = Provider.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```