# Testing Form In Django With A User Object

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-forms

I am working on testing - and I have a little form with a good chunk of logic in the clean method.

My test looks like this:

```
class DependentFormTest(TestCase):

    def test_dependent_form_birthdate_out_of_range(self):
        form_data = {
            'first_name': 'Bill',
            'last_name': 'Robusin',
            'birth_date': '10/12/1801',
            'gender': 'Male',
            'relationship': 'dependent',
            'street_address_1': '123 Any lane',
            'city': 'Billson',
            'state': 'WA',
            'zip': '50133',
        }
        form = DependentForm(data=form_data)
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
```

In my clean method there is a bit where I access some information about the current user. The snippet that fails looks like this:

```
user_benefit = Benefit.objects.get(user=self.user)
```

This line is what causes my test to error with the following error:

`Benefit matching query does not exist`

This is true, because in the test 'user' is 'None'.

How do I set a user in my test so that I can test this forms validity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your test `setUp()` method you could create a user for testing purposes. and then reuse it.

As far as i understand your user comes from the request. So you would need to use django test client to login and post the data into your form.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the user in a form's `clean` method if the user is not set explicitly during the forms initialization (see here: [django: how to access current request user in ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299973/django-how-to-access-current-request-user-in-modelform) )

If you pass the user to the constructor during form initialization, you can also do that in your test.

```
user = User.objects.first() # probably you should think about a better way to obtain a user instance
form = DependentForm(data=form_data, user=user)
self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
```