# Django modelforms, foreignkey filter for data owned by logged in user

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model for which I have created a Model form:

```
class StoreDepartment(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, verbose_name='Store')
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, 
            verbose_name='Department name')
    department_description = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=False, 
            verbose_name='Description')
    archive = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class StoreDepartmentCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StoreDepartment
        exclude = ['id',]

    store = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Store.objects.all())
    department_name = forms.CharField(label="Name", required=True)
    department_description = 
            forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,label="Description")
```

The queryset = Store.objects.all() returns all the stores in the system. How to use a filter to get Store data only owned by the current logged in user.

**Updating the question**

Following is the model which contains the reference for the user:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, verbose_name='User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, verbose_name='Store name')
```

I tried to override the init function for the model form as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, user=None, **kwargs):
        super(StoreDepartmentCreateForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fields['store'].queryset = Store.objects.filter(owner=User)
```

But, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ModelBase'
```

Comment: Many examples are there in SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/7300076/2282638

Comment: The example you showed is to override the save method, while saving the form. But, I am unable to figure out how to modify the query to populate the select box with data owned by the logged in user. Right now the above query shows me all the stores in the system.

Comment: No it is the right method. You have to pass user in init method. How Store and User are connected ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal is it something like this:     
def __init__(self, user=None, **kwargs):
        super(StoreDepartmentCreateForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['store'].queryset = Store.objects.filter(Owner=user)

Comment: why don't you use one more field for storing your user llike `user = models.ForeignKey(User)` this

Comment: I have updated the question, Please have a look.