# How to access request object in admin class so I can get GET params?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django admin class/interface, to which I added a list_filter:

```
class OverallBalanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (format__overall_balances, )
    list_filter = ( OverallBalanceCurrencyFilter, )
    search_fields= ('id',) 
    ordering = ('-on_datetime',)


admin.site.register(OverallBalance, OverallBalanceAdmin)
```

Now, the class OverallBalanceCurrencyFilter has a parameter_name='currencyabbr' (i.e: a parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query) and I would like to access the value of `request.GET.get('currencyabbr', '')` inside `format__overall_balances` function, but since it does not get the request object as a parameter I am a bit puzzled on how to accomplish this.

Does anyone know a way to work around it?

Comment: Paste your `OverallBalanceCurrencyFilter` and `format__overall_balances` code, please.

Comment: It seems someone else has just asked this question very recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727928/