# How to access request object in model admin changelist_view

Tags: python, django

Wish to add hyperlink to one of the model attributes for click-to-call functionality. Then based on the currently logged in user, need to access the 'extension' attribute for the user.
I have extended the django auth.User model to create the Employee master. The Employee has the the 'extension' attribute.

The employee class has user as Foreign Key with OneToOneField as:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    extension = models.IntegerField()
```

In another modeladmin:

```
ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('click_to_call',)
    def click_to_call(self, obj):
            return '<a href="http:///somecall.php?extension=131&phone=%s">%s</a>' % (obj.mobile,"click-to-call")
        click_to_call.allow_tags = True
```

The employee should be able to dial a client mobile by clicking on the above hyperlink. His extension number is passed along with the client's mobile number to the API. HOw do I access  the request object in the def click_to_call? Using django 1.6.5

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to exactly what you're trying to achieve. Why are you resolving view-type issues in the model? I'd just handle the display of information to the user in a *view*, and then you have access to request etc. in there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/781909/jvc26 Why should I not be able to use this view to click-to-call functionality? Why do I need to add another view to achieve this instead of using the existing view? All the employees will not be able to add the client details. So based on login, they will however be able to call using the hyperlink.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2714931/weizhongtu , it shows error: ClientAdmin' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: I wish to access the request object in click_to_call method to resolve this. :(

Comment: This has been previously discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/727928/781909). You essentially need to pass ```request``` into the view.

Comment: I checked this http://stackoverflow.com/q/727928/781909, but could not get it to work. Don't know where I am not able to map it!

Comment: ```def click_to_call(self, obj):``` does not pass request. You need to provide the request as a parameter: ```def click_to_call(self, request, obj):```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/781909/jvc26, this does not work either. Says expected parameters 3, given 2!